# Getting Blank Screen in WebView using Swift

Tags: url, swift3, uiwebview

I am making a simple `webview` using `Swift 3`. But after run am getting only the blank screen.

It is not opening the link which I put in  url request.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL (string: "http://www.google.net");
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(request);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Have you wireUp WebView from Storyboard?

Comment: Yeah i have done that.

Comment: add a delegate and check the delegate methods:
 optional public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)

    optional public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error).

Also you need to add app transport security settings in plist.

Comment: Okay..Check my answer...!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to `YES` under `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary in your .plist file.

Like this Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

write this code in info.plist

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
 </dict>
```

and write this code in viewdid load

```
webView.opaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

try this it might help..