# WkWebView in MacOS remains blank on local or remote content

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, webkit, wkwebview

I'm trying to build a MacOS app that can load websites and extract data from them using webviews, but I can't get webviews to load at all, either with remote content or with local content.

I'm trying to use a very small webview embedded into the main view.  (Ultimately, I don't actually want this to be displayed, or I want it to be as small as possible---I just want the rendered content to extract data.)  Like this:

[image: screenshot of my storyboard]

However, neither loading from a remote url nor loading from a local test html string works.  When I click either the load-from-remote-url button or the load-from-local-test-string button, the print statement I put in there to make sure the function gets called is printed, but there's no change at all to the webview: it just remains a blank white box. It also doesn't throw any kind of error.

Here's the failing code:

webViewTools.swift:

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

extension WKWebView {
    func load(_ urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("can't make url")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        load(request)
    }
}

let testHtml =  "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>"

extension WKWebView {
    func test(){
        loadHTMLString(testHtml, baseURL: nil)
        }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    @IBAction func loadButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        webView.load("https://www.apple.com/")
        print("trying to load from remote")
    }

    @IBAction func linkButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        webView.test()
        print("trying to load local string")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Note: the sandbox is not enabled, and I've added "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to the "App Transport Security Settings" entry in info.plist, so [this prior SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43914157/4386239) does not resolve the problem.

How do I convince the WKWebView to actually, you know, display something? (MacOS 10.14.5, Swift 5, XCode 10.2.1)

Answer (score 7):

Aaaah, I discovered the problem: apparently even if you don't turn the sandbox on, WKWebView totally fails without it.  Not only that, but it fails silently.  When I turned the sandbox on, and then enabled outgoing connections, everything started working right away.